# Assign a Derivate to a new fuction variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, assignment

I'm having a new problem. I'm trying to create a new function from a Derivate of another function, but i'm can't getting it. Someone could help me? I'm thinking that is something in the syntax of the progam that i'm not doing in the right way...Thanks in advance guys[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp4kR.png)

Comment: It appears from the error that velt is already defined. Please clear all definitions (or quit kernel) and define it again. There should be no syntax issue here because defining a function as a derivative of another function is quite legitimate. For instance fun[t_] = D[Sin[t] Exp[t], t] works as expected.

Comment: You need something like `velt[x_] := Module[{t}, D[newpostt[t], t] /. t -> x];` because to need to differentiate w.r.t. a **symbolic** variable and not a number.